# C++ image library - finding pixels of a colour and making them white, everything else black

Tags: c++, image-processing

I'm looking for a C++ image processing library with which I would be able to find all pixels of a certain colour, with a user-specified tolerance, and colour them white and everything else in the picture black. Do you know of any?

If it were a C++ library, not one of plain C ones, which I'm allergic to, it would be a bonus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check OpenCV. It has both C and C++ (based on OO principles) APIs.

Comment: OpenCV was the first library I've looked at in my search but I haven't found what I was looking for. The closes thing was `threshold()` function but it works only for greyscale images and checks only if a pixel is above or below a threshold, while I want to check if it falls into a certain range. Do you know of a function/functions which could do the job?

Comment: I guess what you are looking for is too specific to be directly part of OpenCV. Hence you need to implement it yourself using the basic tools provided by OpenCV. Just iterate over each pixel and check the distance of a pixel from the color you are looking for. If the distance is small enough, you set this pixel to whatever value you like.

Comment: OK, I think it's what I'm going to do.

Answer (score 1):

[OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) can do this task and many more!

Answer (score 1):

Or perhaps a CImg - a wonderful header-only image manipulation library.

http://cimg.sf.net

Comment: I've never heard about CImg before, but it looks promising